# UCAExc:::3.0.7 row column count mismatch

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have some codes for doing my project. There is a access database that have some tables and records. I'm taking this records from access database and I'm creating MS Word document with them. My codes like this

```
public static void partoff(String SalesOrder)
    {

        try {

            ResultSet deneme4,deneme5,deneme6,deneme,deneme0,deneme10,deneme11 = null;
            deneme10=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT GroupName,ID From TableRun Where LID IN (Select DISTINCT strLID from TableResult Where strSO='"+SalesOrder+"') ORDER BY ID");
            ArrayList all_groups=new ArrayList();
            while(deneme10.next()) {
                all_groups.add(deneme10.getString("GroupName"));
                //System.out.println(all_groups.size());
            }
            ArrayList LIDs=new ArrayList();

                deneme11=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT LID,ID FROM TableRun WHERE GroupName IN (SELECT GroupName,ID From TableRun Where LID IN (Select DISTINCT strLID from TableResult Where strSO='"+SalesOrder+"')) ORDER BY ID");
                while(deneme11.next())
                {

                    LIDs.add(deneme11.getString("LID"));
                    System.out.println(LIDs.size());
                }






            for(int qq=0; qq<all_groups.size(); qq++) {


                deneme4=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT  * FROM TableResult WHERE   strSO='" + SalesOrder + "' AND strLID='"+LIDs.get(sayac)+"'");
                deneme5=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT  * FROM TablePARTON WHERE   strSO='" + SalesOrder + "' AND strLID='"+LIDs.get(sayac)+"'");
                deneme6=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT  * FROM TableIW59 WHERE   strSO='" + SalesOrder + "' AND strLID='"+LIDs.get(sayac)+"'");


             while(deneme4.next()) {


                 System.out.println(off[satir1][sayac2+8]=deneme4.getString("DefectDes"));                   
                 if(!off[satir1][sayac2+8].equalsIgnoreCase("Not Disassembled"))
                 {

                     off[satir1][sayac2]=deneme4.getString("strTASK");          
                     off[satir1][sayac2+1]=deneme4.getString("strLID");                 
                     off[satir1][sayac2+2]=deneme4.getString("strPN");              
                     off[satir1][sayac2+3]=deneme4.getString("intQPE");             
                     off[satir1][sayac2+4]=deneme4.getString("intSV");          
                     off[satir1][sayac2+5]=deneme4.getString("intIS");          
                     off[satir1][sayac2+6]=deneme4.getString("intRS");          
                     off[satir1][sayac2+7]=deneme4.getString("intREP");         
                     off[satir1][sayac2+8]=deneme4.getString("DefectDes");  
                     satir1++;
                 }
                 else {
                        //System.out.println(deneme.getString("GroupName"));
                        //satir1=0;
                        //deneme4.next();
                 }


            }

             while(deneme5.next())
             {
                 onn[satir2][sayac2]=deneme5.getString("strPN");    
                 onn[satir2][sayac2+1]=deneme5.getString("intNewOnQty");    
                 onn[satir2][sayac2+2]=deneme5.getString("intRepOnQty");    
                 onn[satir2][sayac2+3]=deneme5.getString("intSVOnQty"); 
                 onn[satir2][sayac2+4]=deneme5.getString("strRemark");

                 satir2++;
             }


             while(deneme6.next())
             {
                if(!deneme6.getString("strNotifType").equals("ER")) {
                     dispon[satir3][sayac2]=deneme6.getString("strNotifType");
                     dispon[satir3][sayac2+1]=deneme6.getString("strPN");               
                     dispon[satir3][sayac2+2]=deneme6.getString("strQty");   
                     dispon[satir3][sayac2+3]=deneme6.getString("strCodeText");
                     dispon[satir3][sayac2+4]=deneme6.getString("strGroupText");    
                     dispon[satir3][sayac2+5]=deneme6.getString("strShortText");   
                     dispon[satir3][sayac2+6]=deneme6.getString("strLongText");                 

                     satir3++;
                }
            }


             if(satir3>0) {

                    int x=0;
                    int y=0;
                    int q=0;

                for(int i=0; i<satir3; i++) {   

                    j=i+1;

                    while(j<=satir3) {

                            if(dispon[i][1].equals(dispon[j][1]) && dispon[i][3].equals(dispon[j][3])&& dispon[i][4].equals(dispon[j][4])){


                                    x = Integer.parseInt(dispon[i][2]);
                                    y = Integer.parseInt(dispon[j][2]);

                                    q = x+y;

                                    dispon[i][2]=Integer.toString(q);

                                    dispon[j][0]="boss";


                            }

                            j++;

                    }
                }
             }


             disponsatir=0;

              for(int i = 0; i < satir3; i++)
                {
                  for(int j = 0; j<7 ;j++)
                  {
                      if(!dispon[i][0].equals("boss"))
                      {
                          dispon_new[disponsatir][j]=dispon[i][j];
                        if(j==6)  disponsatir++;
                      }


                  }
                }


              sayac++;




            if(!all_groups.get(qq).equals(all_groups.get(qq+1)))    {

                create_table1(satir1,all_groups.get(qq).toString());
                sayac3=0;
                sayac2=0;   
                satir1=0;
                satir2=0;
                satir3=0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Success");

        }   catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("NOT Successfully");
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }   
    }
```

It was working nicely yesterday. I changed something in codes but I don't remember what is it. After then I tried to run my codes, I'm getting this error.

```
UCAExc:::3.0.7 row column count mismatch
```

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: `... WHERE GroupName IN (SELECT GroupName,ID From TableRun ...` - Your subquery should only select the GroupName column. You're trying to pass two columns to the IN clause of the outer query.

Comment: Also: **(1)** UCanAccess 3.0.7 is very old. You should upgrade to the latest version. **(2)** Stop using dynamic SQL for queries like this. Use PreparedStatement objects to perform proper parameterized queries. Do a web search for "SQL injection" to learn more.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks man,I'll upgrade my UCanAccess and I'll look PreparedStatement objects. Also your first advice is  correct. I fixed it.